# Memory bandwidth up to 200GB/s and 400GB/s for m1pro and m1max: how to calculate it? And how does different choices of specs affect it?

Tags: memory, apple-silicon

I'm considering buying a new M1pro or M1max and plans to use it for 6~8 years.

However, I'm confused by the memory bandwidth part.

1. Is it a theoretical value solely based on different chipset? i.e. all M1pro models has 200GB/s, and all M1max models has 400GB/s?
2. If yes, then what is the theory and how do we get the numbers exactly? I've checked the [wiki page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Memory_bandwidth) and cannot conclude how exactly do we get the nubmer.
3. If not, and because it says "up to", then how does different models affect the memory bandwidth? For instance, a M1Pro(8CPU 14GPU 16NE) with 16GB of memory, compared to a M1Pro(10CPU 16GPU 16NE) with 32GB of memory, how and how much do they differ in memory bandwidth?

Comment: This is not a duplicated question! My question is more of a theoretical calculation; while the referenced 429140 is more on model preference.

Comment: I'm sure there's some benchmark that will confirm this when it's released, but it's unconfirmed so I'm just leaving this as a comment: It looks like the ram comes in 16gb dies and each block has it's own 100GB/s interface. the 200 and 400 GB/s numbers are kinda theoretical and assume you're accessing 100GB/s from each of the dies at the same time. That's why the speed seems to double when you go up in ram. It's essentially dual and quad channel memory configurations. So in the real world you wouldn't get 400GB/s unless maybe resources are smartly distributed amongst all the dies.